# What are the advantages of ASP.NET/C# in front of PHP and Java EE

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, visual-studio, jakarta-ee

These days a lot of companies use asp.net inspight of php or Java EE even if those two tools are free so what is the advantages of using asp.net over php and Java EE. Is it only because of the IDE? or what?

Comment: Oh, no, please. Also who told you that ASP.NET is not free?

Comment: Two minutes, 59 seconds.

Comment: @Charles, yeah, too much. Depending on the current audience those type of questions rarely survive the 60 seconds barrier.

Comment: i'm still a student don't blame me i'm just trying to know more about asp.net !

Comment: @Houssam, you might want to check out some of the questions in the "Related" list on the right, below the ad banners.  They may prove useful for you.

Comment: @Charles Thanks ! that's what i was doing !